# Footer on the bottom of the page and stop moving the text while hovering over dropdown menu

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my footer to be always displayed on the bottom of the page when there is no enough content. I've tried several solutions but none of them worked. Also, there is a small issue with the dropdown menu - the text moves when I hover over this component. What should I change in my CSS? Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li').hover(function(){
$(this).find('ul>li').stop().slideToggle(250);
});
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
}

p {
    padding: 10px;
}

#navigation ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: auto;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
}

#navigation {
 text-align: center;
}

#navigation ul li {
 float: left;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
 width: 140px;
}

#navigation ul li:hover {
 background: #9D9FA4;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li li {
 background: #3F61A9;
 color: #fff;
 display: none;
}

ul li li:hover {
 background: #9D9FA4;
}

ul li li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}


#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

#headerwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; 
}

#header {
    height: 125px;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 5px;
 position: relative;
}

#navigationwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}

#navigation {
    height: 40px;
    background: #52bf6e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #3ea858;
    margin: 5px;
}

#contentwrap {
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#leftcolumnwrap {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftcolumn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#rightcolumnwrap {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#rightcolumn {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#footerwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

#footer {
    height: 40px;
    background: #9D9FA4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #888a91;
    margin: 5px;
 background-color: #9D9FA4;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#navigationwrap_placeholder {
    display:none;
 height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headerwrap">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="navigationwrap">
        <div id="navigation">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="">main menu</a></li>
   <li><a>test</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="">test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">test4</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
  <div id="navigationwrap_placeholder"></div>
        <div id="leftcolumnwrap">
        <div id="leftcolumn">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="content">
   <br><br>
<p>Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. </p>
   <br><br>
  </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightcolumnwrap">
        <div id="rightcolumn">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footerwrap">
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use position:fixed to put the footer at the bottom of the page.

```
#footerwrap {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

As for the text shifting `slideToggle` seems to be shifting the padding of the test list item. By setting the padding in the style itself it fixes the problem.

```
    <li ><a style="padding:0 38%">test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet that solves your navigation issue. I added comments in the CSS so you can better understand what changes I made. I used some flex-box to fix the issue. Super simple. As for the footer, there are lots of ways you can achieve this so I will post a link to an article that shows you 5 different ways to do it and you can pick whichever one works best for your use case. Hope this helps :)

P.S. As a side note, I noticed in your markup that you had a class called sub-menu which is not being used in your CSS. Not a big deal just thought I'd point it out. You probably have plans for it later on.

[Here are some footer options](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul>li').stop().slideToggle(250);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
}


/* removed display property as it was not needed
   display inline-block was causing the nav item to shift over*/

#navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation {
  text-align: center;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  width: 140px;
}

#navigation ul li:hover {
  background: #9D9FA4;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li li {
  background: #3F61A9;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

ul li li:hover {
  background: #9D9FA4;
}

ul li li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

#headerwrap {
  width: 1000px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  height: 125px;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

#navigationwrap {
  width: 1000px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}


/* Added display flex to container with 
   justify-content center to keep nav items aligned*/

#navigation {
  height: 40px;
  background: #52bf6e;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #3ea858;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

#contentwrap {
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#leftcolumnwrap {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftcolumn {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#rightcolumnwrap {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#rightcolumn {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#footerwrap {
  width: 1000px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
}

#footer {
  height: 40px;
  background: #9D9FA4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #888a91;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #9D9FA4;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navigationwrap_placeholder {
  display: none;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="headerwrap">
      <div id="header">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigationwrap">
      <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">main menu</a></li>
          <li><a>test</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="">test1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">test3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">test4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navigationwrap_placeholder"></div>
    <div id="leftcolumnwrap">
      <div id="leftcolumn">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentwrap">
      <div id="content">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices.
          Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci
          luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. </p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumnwrap">
      <div id="rightcolumn">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footerwrap">
      <div id="footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP also wanted footer positioned at bottom of page.

Comment: Yes. The link I posted showed various ways to make a sticky footer.